# Rails: scaffold. Create admin controller for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I want to create admin interface for existing model User.

What is the simplest way?
I think, it's scaffolding.

Scaffolding in rails is generated by script(`rails generate scaffold`), and there is no options to do it dynamically (like in django), correct?

So how can I create scaffolding controller `AdminUsers` for model `User`? Create `AdminUsers` scaffolding and replace `AdminUser` model by `User`?

What should I do if model will be changed by migrations? Manually update scaffolding controller and views, right? Is there any automation?

Comment: have you looked into ActiveAdmin?

Comment: No, I didn't know about it. Now I'm reading its documentation. I think it's that what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

ActiveAdmin is a neat user interface for your Rails application. It gives you a fully customizable user interface to your models.

Site: http://activeadmin.info/

Demo: http://demo.activeadmin.info/admin

Railscasts Episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin

Comment: Don't ever use ActiveAdmin. More info: http://rubyjunky.com/get-rid-of-your-admin-gem.html

Answer (score 5):

You can generate the files dynamically using scaffolding- the scaffold command can take a namespaced argument.

```
rails generate scaffold Admin::User
```

You don't need another model though- your Admin::UsersController and views should be working with the User model.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it. But I meant "without generating controllers/views" when I said "dynamically".

Answer (score 5):

Using standard solutions such as [activeadmin](http://rubygems.org/gems/activeadmin) or [rails_admin](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails_admin) is the simpliest way. If you want something custom and still wondering how to scaffold controller `AdminUsers` for model `User`, you might want to take a look at [rails-admin-scaffold gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails-admin-scaffold) which automates this process and [an article](http://dhampik.com/blog/rails-admin-scaffold) with more detailed explanation.